# How can I simplify this script?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

Can you help me simplify this script?

This works but I think that there is a easier way to do it, but I can't find it.

The file:

```
Car Brand:Mercedes | Country:Germany | Car Model:300 SL | Year:04-1960
Car Brand:Lamborghini | Country:Italy | Car Model:Miura | Year:10-1970
Car Brand:Aston Martin | Country:UK | Car Model:DBS | Year:12-1965
Car Brand:Ford | Country:United States of America | Car Model:GT40 | Year:09-1966
```

Output:

```
1:Mercedes:Germany:300 SL:61:xxx
2:Lamborghini:Italy:Miura:51:xxx
3:Aston Martin:UK:DBS:56:xxx
4:Ford:United States of America:GT40:55:xxx
```

1,2,3,4 is the number of the line; 61, 52, 56, 55 (current year - year, ignoring the month), xxx insurance company (always the same, this part stopped working)

Script:

```
line=$(awk '{print NR}' file.txt)
brand=$(sed 's/.*Brand:\(.*\) | Country.*/\1/' file.txt)
country=$(sed 's/.*Country:\(.*\) | Year.*/\1/' file.txt)
sed 's/.*Year:\(.*\) | Car.*/\1/; s/^...//' file.txt > cars.txt
age=$(awk -v age="$(date +%Y)" '{print age - $1}' cars.txt)
model=$(sed 's/.*Model:\(.*\)*/\1/' file.txt)
echo "$(paste <(echo "$line") <(echo "$brand") <(echo "$country") <(echo "$age") <(echo "$model") -d ':')" > cars.txt
# sed -i 's/$/:xxx/' cars.txt
cat cars.txt
```

Thank you

Comment: please do not duplicate your question over multiple SE sites https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/637978/72456

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is no dash `-` elsewhere apart from last item, you can do :

```
awk -v year="$(date +%Y)" -F '(-|:| \\| )' '{print NR":"$2":"$4":"$6":"(year-$9)":xxx"}' file.txt
```

`-F` take three field separators, `-` `:` and `|`

Pipe `|` (a single character) is the separator for the 3 regular expressions. `|`(a space followed by |, followed by another space) is one of the separator, to distinguish the pipe in your data file from the pipe as regex separator, we need to escape it with `\\`.

```
-F fs
  --field-separator fs
  Use fs for the input field separator (the value of the FS predefined variable).
```

For more inforamtion : https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp-Field-Splitting

Comment: Can you explain me the last part of this -F '(-|:| \\| )' ( \\| )?

Comment: Thank you but still don't understand this  "\\| " , why does it need to be there if there aren't any \ in the file?

Comment: Updated again, please check.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
sed 's/ *|[^:]*: */:/g' file.txt |
    awk -F: -v OFS=: -v year="$(date +%Y)" '{$1=NR; sub("^.*-","",$NF); $NF=year-$NF; print $0, "xxx"}'
```

Explanation: the `sed` command replaced all of the "| Fieldlabel:" bits with just ":", giving lines like this:

```
Car Brand:Mercedes:Germany:300 SL:04-1960
```

The `awk` command then splits it into colon-delimited fields, replaces the first one with the line number, removes the month from the last one (the date)  and subtracts it from the current year, and finally it's printed with an extra fixed field added at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^/ | /;s/ | [^:]*//g;s/(.*:)..(.*)/\1$(($(date +%Y)\2)):xxx/;=' file |
sed 'N;s/\n//;s/.*/echo "&"/e'
```

Prepend a pipe delimiter in readiness for the line number to be prepended later.

Globally remove text between the pipe delimiter and the next occurrence of the `:` character.

Replace the last field (date) with a bash expression that calculates the years difference from the current year and also append a dummy field `xxx`.

Prepend the current line number to the output.

Pass the contents of the result to a second sed invocation that combines the line number with the contents of that line and evaluates the bash expression by means of the prepended `echo` command.